# Default value of a text field based on radio selection - PHP if

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement, onchange

I need to change the value of a text field (Agerisk2) to a number based on the selection of a radio field (Age)

In the text field additional attributes I have

```
onChange="$Agerisk2"
```

In the text field default value I have:

```
//<code>
$Age = [];
$Agerisk2 = null;

switch ($Age) {
    case $Age "Under 45 years":
        $Agerisk2 = "0";
        break;

    case $Age "45 – 54 years":
        $Agerisk2 = "2";
        break;

    case $Age "55 – 64 years":
        $Agerisk2 = "3";
        break;

    case $Age "64 years or over":
        $Agerisk2 = "4";
        break;
    
    default:
        $Agerisk2 = null;
        break;
}
//</code>
```

Something isn't quite right and I'd really appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to read up on the correct syntax and how [switch/case](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) works. `case $Age "Under 45 years":` is not valid PHP syntax. _Always_ post any error messages you get in full, with a proper explanation of the issue more than just _"Something isn't quite right"_.

Comment: Btw, `onChange="$Agerisk2"` doesn't really make sense either. Not sure what that suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement is invalid. Better use [match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) for it.

Also note your variable naming should match the [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

```
$age     = 47;

$ageRisk = match (true) {
    $age < 45 => 0,
    $age >= 45 && $age <= 54 => 2,
    $age >= 55 && $age <= 64 => 3,
    $age >= 64 => 4,
    default => null
};

echo $ageRisk;
```

prints

```
2
```

If you are below PHP 8 you can fallback to switch, which does not look so nice.

```
switch (true) {
    case $age < 45:
        $ageRisk = 0;
        break;
    case $age >= 45 && $age <= 54:
        $ageRisk = 2;
        break;
    case $age >= 55 && $age <= 64:
        $ageRisk = 3;
        break;
    case $age >= 64:
        $ageRisk = 4;
        break;
    default:
        $ageRisk = null;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Either of these just puts a 2 at the top of each page of my form.

Comment: Your questions code is not about any form usage, but a wrong use of the switch statement. onChange attribute will only call javascript functions, not from PHP.

Comment: I understand the code/usage is wrong which is why I came here for help. The objective isn't to print a 2 at the top of my form though. Sorry for my lack of overall experience but I am trying to learn.

"I need to change the value of a text field (Agerisk2) to a number based on the selection of a radio field (Age)"

Comment: I suggest you create a new question posting your form code and detailed problem description. This is absolutely not clear in this one :D

Comment: I will expand with a new question. Thank you